# Use shared_ptr in Game Engine layout?

Tags: c++, game-engine, shared-ptr

I have written a little game engine in c++ and it works ok but is not the best performance wise. I also learned a lot and I want to redo it now. But last time I heavily used shared_ptr for classes like gui textures and model wrappers (that hold i.e. the 3d position and the opengl vao). I've heared that shared_ptr should not really be used, but I dont really know how to do it any other way. Here's the pseudo-code-like layout:

This code is not complete or working but I want to share the idea of my layout

```
// d3 stands for 3d
class D3Model {
    VAO vao;
    bool useBloom;
    unsigned int texture;
    // ... and so on

    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<D3Model>> models; // current idea, approach 1
    static std::vector<D3Model> models1; // different approach (2)

    D3Model() {
        models.push_back(shared_from_this()); // app.1
        models1.push_back(*this);
    }
}


// main file
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<D3Model> model = std::make_shared<D3Model>();
    model->setTexture(0); // ignore the non sense content

    D3Model model1;
    model1.setTexture(0); // would not get updated in the vector

    while(true) {
        model->increaseRotation(1);
        model1.increaseRotation(1);
        Renderer::render();
    }
}

// different file
class Renderer {
    static void render() {
        for(const auto& all : D3Model::models) {
            // render model
        }

        for(const auto& all : D3Model::models1) {
            // render model1, would not have increased rotation
        }
    }
}
```

For more clarification, imagine the following use of the engine:
After hitting play on a start screen, the engine loads some 3d models from files and stores them. One of them gets rotated every frame and every one of them gets rendered. Maybe some other models must be loaded after because of a change in gameplay (Player joined...). Then they all get deleted when the user returns to the main menu. My problem with approach 2 is that I'd have to update the vector everytime the rotation of the model is increased, whereas that would automatically be handled with approach 1. However, I have heared that shared_ptr is bad for performance.

Is shared_ptr for this case the best solution or should I just use normal objects? But my problem with that is how would I apply changes to the object (the setTexture for example) without having to update the vector content. And raw pointers arent really good either. How is something like that done?
Thanks, unreal

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr` when you need shared ownership management. If `static std::vector<D3Model> models;` works then you likely didn't need shared ownership management in the first place. Though if `models` needs to grow over time, pointers and references to `D3Model` wont stay valid (which is something you didn't have to worry about while using `std::shared_ptr`. So it might not be the best container.

Comment: Well, I've not yet implemented the vector<D3Model> version (approach 2), but I could only get it working with updating the vector everytime I change anything in one of the models (am I correct?), which obviously would not be very fast (find the similar object in the vector via some sort of id, erasing it and pushing the "new" version). Models will probably have one big "grow" when the world is loading, even though it should be able to load models at any given time for more flexible use

Comment: Well if you want to allow it to grow at any time, you have to assume it will grow at any thing. So you may have invalidation issues. I don't see why you need to erase and re-add elements to change them. A `vector` is a mutable container, you can just change the elements directly. And finding an element by index in a vector is constant time with little overhead. It's not slow at all.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ml7lxi This code should not work with the problem that texture of m is zero in the method rendering, right? Thats what I was talking about [Edit: Added an updateInVector method: http://prntscr.com/ml7moq , where texture of m is 1, but is this the most efficient way to do that?]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to automatically maintain a list of instances. This approach *can* work but is full of traps and not usually worth the effort. At the very least you would need `models` to store pointers to `D3Model`. Right now every time a `D3Model` is created you cause another one to be inserted into `models` in an infinite loop. You will also have the problem that when a `D3Model` is destroyed (for example if `m` was in another function) you would have a dangling pointer to that instance. And that's not to mention copy and move constructors and operators.

Comment: Instead, just operate directly on `models`. Use `models.emplace_back(); auto & m = models.back();` to get a new model. But again, beware of reference invalidation.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ml7qbf So something like that?

Comment: Something like that, but you can just use `models.emplace_back();`. It will default construct an instance in-place in the container. You can alternatively supply construction arguments to `emplace_back`. For example if you have a `D3Model::D3Model(unsigned int)` constructor you could use `models.emplace_back(my_value);` which would make a new `D3Model` using that constructor with the argument's value being `my_value;`.

Comment: Ok, I am going to use this! Thank you very much

Comment: Because you haven't shown that you've addressed it, I'll warn you one last time about invalidation. If you `emplace_back` or otherwise insert into a `std::vector` such that it's capacity grows, all existing references to it's elements can no longer be used. Same thing if you remove an element from the vector, all references to elements after that one are also invalidated. Either `reserve` enough so that the vector can never possibly reallocate, use a different container or use a technique to avoid object relocation, like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<D3Model>>`.

Comment: Yeah right, I guess I'll use a list then

Answer (score -1):

Ok you can create yor own RefCouner class like me:

```
/// RefCounter.hpp
#pragma once
class RefCounter {
public:

    RefCounter();

    RefCounter(const RefCounter&);

    RefCounter& operator=(const RefCounter&);

    void grab();

    usize reference() const;

    bool release();

protected:

    virtual void finalize();

    virtual ~RefCounter();

private:

    usize _reference;

};


template<typename T>
struct ref {

    inline ref() : class_ptr (nullptr) {}

    inline ref(T* obj) : class_ptr (obj) { if(class_ptr) class_ptr->grab(); }

    inline ref(const ref& other) : class_ptr (other.class_ptr) { if(class_ptr) class_ptr->grab(); }

    inline ref& operator=(T* obj) {
        if(obj)
            obj->grab();
        if(class_ptr)
            class_ptr->release();
        class_ptr = obj;
        return *this;
    }

    inline ref& operator=(const ref& other){
        T* obj = other.class_ptr;
        if(obj)
            obj->grab();
        if(class_ptr)
            class_ptr->release();
        class_ptr = obj;
        return *this;
    }

    T* get() const {
        return class_ptr;
    }

    operator T*() const {
        return class_ptr;
    }

    T* operator->() const {
        return class_ptr;
    }

    inline ~ref() {
        if(class_ptr)
            class_ptr->release();
    }

private:
    T* class_ptr;
};

/// RefCounter.cpp


RefCounter::RefCounter() : _reference(0){

}

RefCounter::RefCounter(const RefCounter&) : _reference(0) {

}

RefCounter& RefCounter::operator=(const RefCounter&) {
    return *this;
}

void RefCounter::grab() {
    _reference++;
}

usize RefCounter::reference() const {
    return _reference;
}

bool RefCounter::release() {
    if(_reference > 1) {
        _reference--;
        return false;
    } else {
        _reference = 0;
        finalize();
        return true;
    }
}

void RefCounter::finalize() {
    delete this;
}

RefCounter::~RefCounter() {
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps with the original problem.

Comment: Then perhaps you should explain why `std::shared_ptr` isn't acceptable, why this solution is better and how to use it. This answer seems incomplete as it is now.

Comment: Note that it seems like only objects that derive from `RefCounter` (or implement an equivalent interface) can be referenced by `ref` which is an intrusive design. For example it doesn't work to refer to types from external libraries without an extra wrapper. It also doesn't seem to support move semantics.

Comment: for example: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1_i_reference_counted.html
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_reference.html

Comment: Yep, I've played around with irrlicht before. And it shows that this approach certainly can work but it does have it's drawbacks, including those I noted. But I distinctly remember how annoying having an exposed `grab` and `release` was. And if I'm not mistaken, that engine predates c++11 where the standard smart pointers and move semantics were introduced. Edit : First release was in 2006.